# Proving affine independence of $(k_0,\dotsc,k_0^N),\dotsc,(k_N,\dotsc,k_N^N)$ in $\mathbb{R}^N$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, affine-geometry

In a course called "Topics in Geometry and Topology", my teacher showed this in the case $k_i\in\mathbb{N}$ for all $i$ -- or rather, said he'd restrict himself to said case, but that the general case wasn't that much different.  He said that these are affinely independent iff a certain matrix is nonsingular. Too bad I didn't write it down. The matrix should be:

$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
k_1-k_0 & \dots & k_N-k_0 \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
k_1^N-k_0^N & \dots & k_N^N-k_0^N
\end{array}\right).$$

Or perhaps its transpose. Then he said something about subtracting the first column. So I did:

$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
k_1-k_0 & \dots & k_N-k_1 \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
k_1^N-k_0^N & \dots & k_N^N-k_1^N
\end{array}\right).$$

Then he said something about expanding along line 1 and obtaining a Vandermonde determinant. And I'm like: wait a sec, Vandermonde has powers, not differences of powers! I have no reason to believe adding $(k_0,\dotsc,k_0^N)$ would leave the determinant unchanged as the passage above did. And I completely fail to see how Vandermonde matrices appear here. So how do I go about proving this has nonzero determinant?

**Extra**

In the book *Simplicial Structures in topology*, which he co-authored, my teacher has the following proof:

[image]

I am under the impression this needs to assume $i_0=0$, and I also can't quite get how he got the first equation, since there is no coordinate equal to 1… besides, $2x+1$ coordinates should give $2n+1$ equations, and there are $2n+2$ there… any ideas how to solve these problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Said teacher here.

The statement and proof of the theorem are ugly brief approximations. FIY, it was  2015-10-19 (in-class) when the proof was given. Same notation: 
$P^k = (k,k^2,\ldots, k^N)$.

Let $k_0$, $k_1$, $\ldots$ , $k_N$ be integers (distinct numbers), 
then the corresponding 
$P^{k_0}$, $P^{k_1}$, $\ldots$, $P^{k_N}$   are (**affinely**) linearly independent 
if and only if 
the $N+1$ vectors in homogeneous coordinates
$$[1,k_j,k_j^2,\ldots, k_j^N]$$
are lin.ind.

Then [Vandermonde matrixness](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Vandermonde_Determinant) occurs.

The formulation in the screenshot-book is kind of obscure, but trying (and failing) to state the same fact. Difference between affine and vector space.

Comment: To prove that if and only if, I can take the matrix obtained with those vectors, subtract the first column from each of the other ones (determinant stays the same since at each step the determinant would get an extra term which is the determinant of the previous matrix, but with an extra column equal to minus the first one, but that has determinant zero), then expand along line 1 to see the determinant is the same as that of my matrix, whose non-singularity I know to characterize affine independence of those points. And this new matrix is clearly Vandermonde.